# Did Microsoft eliminate the PnP Template Gallery or has it moved?

Tags: template, pnp, open-source

I found this post from 2016:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/pnp-templates-gallery-open-source-provisioning-templates/

“At Microsoft Ignite 2016, in Atlanta, we proudly announced the availability of the new “PnP Templates Gallery” portal, which is available at the following URL: https://templates-gallery.sharepointpnp.com.”

“The basic idea around this new portal, is to have a public and shared repository for PnP provisioning templates, which anybody can download and use for free. Moreover, we hope that many community members will like to share their own templates with the community. In the following figure, you can see the home page of the PnP Templates Gallery.”

Sooo why is it a dead link now? Did it get moved? Is Microsoft moving away from PnP Templates?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any official deprecation messages (maybe I missed something). But it looks like they decided to transform it into something more solid and supported.

At the end of 2018 a [SharePoint Online Provisioning Service](https://provisioning.sharepointpnp.com/) (in beta as of now) was introduced:

> You can use this service (when released) to provision different kind of sites and site collections to your tenant.

Under the hood, it uses PnP templates.

To see it in action check out this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/_pG-Eue1-K4?t=2146)